# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in a CodeIgniter View

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting an `unexpected end of file` error on my CodeIgniter View.

I have pasted the PHP code at http://codepad.org/S12oXE4t.

This code passed various online PHP syntax tests, but I don't know why still it shows me the below error while I was trying to run in WAMP Server.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
 E:\wampserver\www\CodeIgniter\application\views\layouts\default.php on line 676
```

For reference, `line 676` is the last line in the code. What did I do wrong?

Comment: you missed a closing brace somewhere

Comment: I tried the code, and it ran until it groused about base_url.  Did you make a mistake in copying it?

Comment: In case you encounter an error message you don't understand, it's not that wrong to pay a visit to: [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456)

Comment: I checked in almost all the online tools at http://www.google.co.in/search?q=php+online+syntax+check&aq=0&oq=php+online+sy&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_rn=1&gs_ri=serp&pq=share%20code%20online&cp=12&gs_id=2x&xhr=t&q=php+syntax+checker&pf=p&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&oq=php+syntax+c&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.aGc&fp=aaf6447fe4e1119c&bpcl=40096503&biw=1280&bih=699

Comment: And you have to load the `url` helper before using `base_url()`

Comment: If that's a } or ; IDE must point out the issue. I tested in various IDEs but no IDE pointed the error.

Comment: You do not really expect somebody to go through your tremendous file just to fiddle with your parsing issue, won't you?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Check your [short_open_tag](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) setting (use `<?php phpinfo() ?>` to see its current setting).

Comment: You should include what `short_open_tag` does, and what it should be set to and why in the answer itself.

Comment: I would vote you thousands times if I could, just saved me after of 4 hours smashing my head on the keyboard trying to fix disasters from some random wotsit whom at the end it came up that he only likes to put deprecated shorttags everywhere.

Comment: Wow!! this is such an important item - I wasted almost 2 hours trying to trouble shoot when the solution is this simple

Comment: Have to say this saved me from a potential head ache as well.

Comment: In case you are using command line, you can type `php -i | grep short_open_tag ` instead of `<?php phpinfo() ?>`. I guess default value is Off which means you have to use `<?php  ?>`  instead of only `<? ?>`

Answer (score 21):

`Unexpected end of file` means that something else was expected before the PHP parser reached the end of the script.

Judging from your **HUGE** file, it's probably that you're missing a closing brace (`}`) from an `if` statement.

Please at least attempt the following things:

1. Separate your code from your view logic.
2. Be consistent, you're using an end `;` in some of your embedded PHP statements, and not in others, ie. `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` vs `<?php echo $this->layouts->print_includes() ?>`. It's not required, so don't use it (or do, just do one or the other).
3. Repeated because it's important, separate your concerns. There's no need for all of this code.
4. Use an IDE, it will help you with errors such as this going forward.

Comment: If that's a } or ; IDE must point out the issue. I tested in various IDEs but no IDE pointed the error.

Comment: @lock Not if the error is in an include somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Usually the problem is not closing brackets (}) or missing semicolon (;)

Comment: If that's a } or ; IDE must point out the issue. I tested in various IDEs but no IDE pointed the error.